# Confused between normal and binomial dist.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

The fish in a lake have weights that are normally distributed with a mean of 1.3 kg and
a standard deviation of 0.2 kg.

(b) John catches 6 fish. Calculate the probability that at least 4 of the fish weigh more than 1.4 kg.

In checking the marking scheme of the exam which contained this problem, I found out a mentioning to the binomial theorem. Here is a screen shot of weird answer for me (since it mentions a binomial dist. when the problem is talking about Normal dist.) and I wish if somebody explains to me what's going on with the solution to this part (part b) in specific
Image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the probability that (1) a fish weighs more than $1.4$kg, or (2) a fish weighs $1.4$kg or less, using the normal distribution

If fish weights are independent, you can then use the binomial distribution to work out the probability that (1) $4$, $5$ or $6$ fish weigh more than $1.4$kg or (2) $0$ or $1$ fish weigh $1.4$kg or less.

Note that the $\le$ in (b) should be $\lt$

Comment: Still didn't get it sorry :(
from where did you base your assumption that fish weight is independent? Why the binomial is used here? Also where is that number (0.3085) came from? What is that Y thing in method 1 and that X thing in method 2?.
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Independent because you need to assume it to answer the question (how does the weight of the first fish affect the weight of the second fish). 

Binomial because you want the probability of a certain number of successes form a certain larger number of attempts.  

$0.3085$ comes from the normal distribution for the probability that a fish weighs more than $1.4$kg.  

Each of these are rather basic statistics questions which you have probably just been taught.